# Which takes precedence, id or name, when both are defined for the same bean in the XML config?

Tags: spring

Does Spring provide a deterministic behaviour for when the same beans take id and name, having  both different values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bean can have only one name but multiple names or alias. What do you mean by precedence? In which case any kind of precedence could be applied?

Comment: if I give <bean id="anId" name="aName" ...> will I be able to retrieve it by both anId and aName? Or would one override the other?

Comment: @Pomario: You can retrieve it by both. Sorry, I didn't understood you.